# Angularでブログサイトを作っています。作成したブログページのデータの持たせ方について質問です。

Tags: javascript, angular6

angular7 を使って blog サイトを作成しています。
いろんなコンポーネントを使ってブログの部品を作ってまして、最終的にブログを作成ってやった時の書き出すデータについてお聞きします。

一つはHTMLとして書き出してそのHTMLを保存するやり方と、もう一つはブログを作成するjsonデータを保存するやり方です。

HTML自体をデータとして保存した場合は、ページを見るときは innerHtml で表示すれば簡単かなと思っていまして、jsonデータをデータとした場合はcomponentから画面を生成して表示させる方法と２種類　実現方法があるかと思っているのですが、　書き出したブログページは　どちらで持たせた方が良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

angularをご使用でしたらjson一択でしょう
htmlで持たした場合より保守が容易となるはずです